# async each passing result to next, eachWaterfall?

Tags: node.js

I am looking for some combination of `async.eachSeries()` and `async.waterfall()` where I can run the same function repeatedly in series on entries in an array, but pass the result along to the next iteration for use in the function. Is there any built in function for this?

At the moment I am considering updating an external variable and using `eachSeries` but some sort of `eachWaterfall` would be ideal, or is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `async.reduce` or `async.reduceRight` to achieve that.

Here's an example to add all the values in the array, passing on the current sum at each iteration

```
var async = require('async');

async.reduce([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(memo, item, callback) {
    callback(null, memo + item);
}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```